# How to @Autwired MessageSource in spring into Entity class correctly?

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have the following entity in spring boot application:

```
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Audited
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
@Table(name = "currency", catalog = "currency_db")
public class Currency implements java.io.Serializable {
    
    @Autowired
    Messages messages;
```

As for message, it just a container of spring MessageSource here it is:

```
@ApplicationScope
@Component
@Slf4j
public class Messages {

    @Autowired
    private MessageSource messageSource;

    private MessageSourceAccessor accessor;

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {       
        accessor = new MessageSourceAccessor(messageSource, Locale.ENGLISH);
        log.info("Messages initialized");
    }

    public String get(String code) {
        return accessor.getMessage(code);
    }

}
```

I'm getting the following error when run mvn clean install. Any idea what I'm missing here?

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: com.company.currencyservice.Messages, at table: currency, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(messages)]
```

It's looks like hibernate think it's a column. Thanks.

Comment: Entities are not Spring beans and therefor you cannot use dependendeny injection in entites. Why do you want to use the Messages in the entity?

Comment: I want to return String that available in a property file

Comment: But why from the entity?

Comment: cause the string is xml field of the entity which means if I don't use it, the entity

Comment: will not have the string when sending to client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entities are not Spring beans and therefor you cannot use dependency injection in entities.

If you want to access a Spring bean from within an entity you can use a helper class like this:

```
@Service
public class ApplicationContextProvider implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private static ApplicationContext context;

    public static <T> T bean(Class<T> beanType) {
        return context.getBean(beanType);
    }

    public static Object bean(String name) {
        return context.getBean(name);
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(@SuppressWarnings("NullableProblems") ApplicationContext ac) {
        context = ac;
    }

}
```

Then you can use `ApplicationContextProvider.getBean(Messages.class)` to get access to the Messages.

Comment: There is no getBean in the class, can you update the class

Comment: I have used the bean method and i get the Meesages but no access to the methods

Comment: DO I need to init it with the Message on applciation start if yes how?

Comment: No you don't have to do anything. Because this class implements ApplicationContextAware the method setApplicationContext will be called. Or did you ask anything else?